# Deploying Commit Phase Fails in Publishing

Tags: 2013, publishing

I have created a new setup for SDL Tridion. When I am trying to publish, it is getting failed in deploying phase.

"No Data Access Object Factory for defaultDB. This exception is thrown if the license is not valid, not present or expired and the default file system storage is not defined."

I am using the same license file which I am using for SDL Tridion. I have placed that file in bin\config folder of httpupload application and mentioned the path in the cd_storage_conf and cd_deployer_conf files. I am not sure, what is going wrong here.

I have not mentioned defaultfilesystem as I want it to go to DB. if I mention default filesystem, then it is getting published to file system correctly. With DB it is giving this issue.

Please Help

Thanks,
Sharad Sangal

Comment: Could you post the ItemTypes section of your cd_storage_conf.xml file? Just make sure you exclude any potentially sensitive information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is something wrong with your `License File` or it's entry to the cd storage config file.

Please check the following:

1. if you have valid entry in `"cd_storage_conf.xml`" for the license
2. check that license does have a key for "`Tridion CD Broker`"

also, below Post could be helpful as well

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571215/no-data-access-object-for-audiencemanagerprofile

Comment: AND remember that Tridion licenses are usually bound to a hostname. Chances are that your new machine is named something else than the original, making your license invalid. Contact Customer Support to request a new license file.

Comment: @Saurabh Gangwar : Thanks Bro... the link you shared helped. It was the access issue over the IIS User. I modifed the access rights and it got resolved.